# How do you calculate area within separate 100m elevational bands from a DEM in R?

Tags: r, dem, elevation

I am trying to calculate the area within each 100m band of a digital elevation model (DEM) raster in R. Does anyone have suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: You need to provide some more detail on exactly what you are after and what you have already tried. Have you classified a DEM into 100m intervals and want the area for each interval? Do you have 100m contours and want area within each one? It is quite unclear as to what you are after. It is also important to show us how you have gone about this, which may also given a better idea to what you want. Please read our FAQ to have a better understanding in the basic expectations of a question.

Comment: The question was answered based on what was provided in the original post.

Comment: I did sort of guess a bit about what your Q was asking. If your Q showed your code reading in a DEM, then plotting the map, and then saying "How do I find the areas between all the 100m intervals from 0 to the top of the DEM?" that might help, especially if you've tried some code and failed - showing the code and any errors etc.

Answer (score 4):

The area of a raster that satisfies some condition is the sum of that condition as a logical variable times the area of the pixels. For a raster in a projected coordinate system (ie not lat-long) that pixel area is the product of the resolution.

So for this DEM:

```
> dem
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 660, 863, 569580  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 20.34325, 20.34325  (x, y)
extent     : 340214.9, 357771.2, 507174.9, 520601.4  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +units=m +no_defs 
source     : haweswaterdem.tif 
names      : haweswaterdem
```

The area in the interval [100, 200) is:

```
> sum(values(dem)>=100 & values(dem)<200) * prod(res(dem))
[1] 13499307
```

and you could loop over the 100,200 limits to get all the 100m ranges.

Or you could cut the DEM values by a set of bounds using `cut` and then tabulate and multiply by the cell area:

```
> range(values(dem))
[1] 145.0000 827.6714
> bounds = seq(100, 900, by=100)
> bounds
[1] 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900
> hband = cut(values(dem), bounds)
> table(hband) * prod(res(dem))
hband
 (100,200]  (200,300]  (300,400]  (400,500]  (500,600]  (600,700]  (700,800] 
13507584.4 69286843.7 51212446.7 44499004.7 32975407.5 18055359.9  5936235.5 
 (800,900] 
  246653.4
```

These should be the total areas in each band. Note these intervals are "left-open and right-closed", so the first band here includes 200 unlike my first code above with the simple test which didn't include 200.

If your raster is in a lat-long system then the area of each cell you need to multiply by is no longer a constant, but you can get the area of each cell using `area(lat_long_dem)` and multiply element-wise.

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick.